# Unable to save my admin.py changes in my model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am pretty new to django. I am trying to save my admin.py **list_editable** changes in my model for the following field **foodQuality**. I am using 'def clean(self):' in my model for validationError and if there is no validation error. I need to save my changes. But it is not saving the right decimal value i recently entered.I tried using **self.cleaned_data** I m geting the following error '**object has no attribute 'cleaned_data**'

```
class DashBoard(models.Model):
    """Dashboard to be used to upload all my items"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    tranScription = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    videoUrl = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    audioUrl = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    imageUrl = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    foodQuality = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00))
    ambience = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00))
    cleanliness = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00))
    mediaType = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default ='mp4')
    date = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default= datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    isUploaded = models.BooleanField(max_length = 255, default = False)

    def clean(self):
        if foodQuality < 0 or foodQuality > 1:
           raise ValidationError(u'%s is not between 0 and 1' % value)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title




class DashBoardModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model = models.DashBoard
     actions = ['delete_model']
     ordering = ['id']
     list_display = ['title',
                     'tranScription',
                     'foodQuality',
                     'ambience',
                     'cleanliness',
                     'videoUrl',
                     'audioUrl',
                     'imageUrl',
                     'mediaType',
                     'date',
                     'isUploaded']

     """ Following fields are made editable """
     list_editable = ('foodQuality', 'ambience', 'cleanliness')

     """ Below provides Link field in admin panel. Made Clickable"""
     list_display_links = ('videoUrl', 'imageUrl', 'audioUrl')

     """ Below provides searchFields against which search is made"""
     search_fields = ('title',
                      'mediaType',
                      'tranScription',
                      'foodQuality',
                      'ambience',
                      'cleanliness')

     fieldsets = (
         (
             ('Permissions'),
             {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}
         ),
         (
             ('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login',)}
         )
     )

     def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
         queryset.delete()

     def VIDEOURL(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='{url}'>{url}</a>", url=obj.firm_url)


admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.DashBoard, DashBoardModel)
```

Comment: Actually, What are you trying to validate here?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I am trying to validate the above fields foodQuality, ambience, cleanliness

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Is there a way were i can save only a single row..Inpsite of validation error in multiple fields ?